# Elasticsearch and geo_shape

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to add some geographic features to an existing application using **elasticsearch 1.1.2**. This application have some `person`, with an attribute `pin` representing a geolocalized point.

Here is the mapping:

```
{"person":{"properties":{"pin":{"type":"geo_point"}}}}
```

Here is the an example of an update of a person :

```
{"doc":{
  "full_name":"Oleta Yost",
  "pin":{"lat":47.123, "lon":-1.15}
}}
```

And my query :

```
{ "from":0,
  "size":24,
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "and":[
          {"or":[
            {"term": /* some term filter */ },
            {"term": /* some term filter */ }
          ]},
          { "geo_shape":{
              "person.pin":{
                "shape":{
                  "type":"envelope",
                  "coordinates":[[46,47],[-10,10]]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "query":{
        "query_string":{
          "fields":["person.full_name^10"],
          "query":"full_name:\"Oleta Yost\""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query is raising an exception :

```
Field [person.pin] is not a geo_shape
```

I tried a lot of solutions

- using a string or an array to define my `pin` update, e.g.)
- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10500

I have no idea where is my issue... Can you point me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above query uses [geoshape query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) which works only on fields with type [geoshape](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html).
In the above mapping the field is [geopoint](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html).

One way would be to change the type to geoshape :

```
"person": {
      "properties": {
         "pin": {
            "type": "geo_shape"
         }
      }
   }
```

And the json data for pin would be :

```
pin : {
   "type" : "Point",
   "coordinates" : [ 46,47]
}
```